# Any way to scope functions to a group of different templates in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say that I've got multiple templates:

```
<template name="orderForm">

  {{> photographyServicesForm}}
  {{> videographyServicesForm}}
  {{> onlineProductsForm}}

</template>
```

And then the JS files for the corresponding templates (includes the rendered, created, helpers, events, etc.)

```
photography_services_form.js
videography_services_form.js
online_products_form.js
order_form.js
```

I have functions that I want shared between `onlineProductsForm` and `photographyServicesForm`, but not `videographyServicesForm`.

I don't want to put the functions all into the `order_form.js` file because then it would be massive and unwieldy. I obviously also don't want to duplicate the same function definitions in each different template.

Is there any way to do this, or do I have to just put everything into the `order_form.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another JS file where you put shared functions between some of your templates, and export them to the global namespace by not using the `var` keyword when declaring them.

`lib/order_form_common.js` (using a lib folder prefix to load this file first)

```
sharedOnRendered = function(){};

sharedHelpers = {
  helper1: function(){},
  helper2: function(){}
};

sharedEvents = {
  "click p": function(){},
  "submit form": function(){}
};
```

Finally, use these shared definitions in corresponding template logic JS files.

`photography_services_form.js`

```
Template.photographyServicesForm.onRendered(sharedOnRendered);

Template.photographyServicesForm.helpers(sharedHelpers);

Template.photographyServicesForm.events(sharedEvents);
```